# flatten лист из разных типов данных python

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать правильный  `flatten list` для сиквенса ниже:

```
[[y, f, r], [[q, "e"],  [24, {"aa": "vaddlue"}], 35], "eee", [45, 15, 36], [57], 26, [[88], [90, 30, [[[5]]]]]]
```

пробовала сделать так, но мой метод не охватывает все затрагиваемые варианты в подсписках

```
def flatten_list(preobrjenie):
    flat_list = []
    for element in preobrjenie:
        if type(element) is list:
            for item in element:
                if type(item) is dict:
                    for key, value in item.items():
                        flat_list.append(key)
                        flat_list.append(value)
                else:
                    flat_list.append(item)
        elif type(element) is dict:
            for key, value in element.items():
                flat_list.append(key)
                flat_list.append(value)
        else:
            flat_list.append(element)
    return flat_list
```

Answer (score 4):

Интересная задачка.

```py
from collections import abc  # Абстрактные типы контейнеров


def flatten(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, abc.Iterable) and not isinstance(obj, str):  # Если объект является итерируемым и не строка
        if isinstance(obj, abc.Mapping):  # Если объект является маппингом (словарь)
            yield from flatten(obj.items())  # Рекурсивно вызываем для пар (ключ, значение) словаря
        else:  # Если объект итерируемый, но не словарь
            for item in obj:  # Перебираем его элементы
                yield from flatten(item)  # Рекурсивно вызываем функцию для каждого из них
    else:  # Если объект не итерируемый или строка
        yield obj  # Возвращаем его самого


inp = [['y', 'f', 'r'], [['q', "e"],  [24, {"aa": "vaddlue"}], 35], "eee", [45, 15, 36], [57], 26, [[88], [90, 30, [[[5]]]]]]

print(list(flatten(inp)))
```

Вывод:

```py
['y', 'f', 'r', 'q', 'e', 24, 'aa', 'vaddlue', 35, 'eee', 45, 15, 36, 57, 26, 88, 90, 30, 5]
```