# создание из составного списка, плоский список

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужна функция которая получает в качестве аргумента составной список, а возвращает плоский список

```
Параметр lst - список, который может содержать другой список
    
>>> flatten_list([])
[]
>>> flatten_list([1,2,3])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> flatten_list([1,2,[3,4],5,6])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> flatten_list([[[[1],2],3],4,[5,[6,[7]]]])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

код попытки:

```
def flatten_list(lst):
    flat_list = []
        for sublist in lst:
            for item in sublist:
                flat_list.append(item)
    return flat_list
```

Таким способом можно раскрыть 2D список, как из этого сделать для 3D, 4D списка и т.д Рекурсия ? Как ее можно реализовать в данной функции ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Раскрыть список / преобразовать список списков (2D) в плоский список (1D)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/837424/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-2d-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-1d) и еще с десяток подобных на ruSO

Comment: Здесь идет речь о большом количестве списков внутри списка.

Comment: ок, давайте я поищу вместо вас... [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1214651/flatten-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-python) - не оно разве?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158532/5741205

Answer (score 3, accepted):

есть наверное средства библиотеки numpy и т.д., но если в лоб встроенными средствами, то можно так:

```
def flatten_list(arr):
    res = []
    for obj in arr:
        res += flatten_list(obj) if isinstance(obj, (list, tuple, set)) else [obj]

    return res
    

print(flatten_list([[[[1],2],3],4,[5,[6,[7], {1,2,3,4}]]]))
```

данная функция работает со списками (`list`), кортежами (`tuple`) и множествами (`set`) и рекурсивно проходит до самых глубоких вложений

если требуется, чтобы она еще и словари переваривала, тогда ее слегка надо доработать, добавив такую возможность